# Facebook API: Dialog which allows users to select photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook App development.  Does Facebook have any prebuilt dialogs so that (with appropriate authentications) I can query a user to select photos?  I don't want to have to build such a dialog myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question as of the time of writing is that there is no such prebuilt dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all photos of the user after taking extended permission of user_photos.
if you are using  login button then you can take extended permission like this

```
 <fb:login-button perms="user_photos" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

if you are using php sdk then you can taken extended permission by login url like this

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
       array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'user_photos'
        )
);
```

after authenticaltion you are having now the access token. From that access token you can get all photos of the user like this

```
$photos=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='.Your Access Token));
foreach ($photos->data as $friend)
{
?>
<img src="<?=$friend->source?>" width="50" height="50">
<?php    
}
```

I hopt it will work :P

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not quite what I'm looking for.  I know how to simply download all of the photos.  Rather, I want the user to select a few of their photos for me to download and use.  I was hoping that there was a Facebook-built photo selection dialog that I could use rather than having to build one of my own.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official solution for that. You'll have to build your own dialog utilizing Facebook's SDK.

However, this jQuery plugin does the job perfectly. You can even use it as a starting point.
https://github.com/YarGnawh/jQuery-Facebook-Photo-Selector

Good luck!